# firebase auth not working after deploying to heroku. Still works in dev at localhost:4200

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

After deploying my Angular 7 app to heroku; my firebase authentication for Google and Facebook no longer work. Both display the same error message (below). Even in incognito mode they both display the same error message (same as the one below).

I've already whitelisted myDomain.com and myDomain.herokuapp.com in my firebase authorized domains. I've also added myDomain.herokuapp.com to my google dev console's authorized domains.

```
glogin() {
    this.socialLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
fbLogin() {
        this.socialLogin(new auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
      }
socialLogin(provider) {
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log('Sign in with google: ', user);
    }).catch(() => {
    // Todo - something went wrong
  });
  }
```

Error i'm getting is:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '__/auth/handler'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '__/auth/handler'
```

and

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '__/auth/iframe'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '__/auth/iframe'
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: Network Error
    at main.115259c96fcb9456163d.js:1
    at o (main.115259c96fcb9456163d.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.ef2a861f18352d657dcf.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.ef2a861f18352d657dcf.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.ef2a861f18352d657dcf.js:1)
    at invoke (polyfills.ef2a861f18352d657dcf.js:1)
    at n.args.<computed> (polyfills.ef2a861f18352d657dcf.js:1)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you struggled like me even after implementing the above method, just go to your Firebase console and under 'Sign-in method', on the 'Authorized domains' tab, add your Heroku app domain.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by going into my prod environment and in my firebase config, changing authdomain from myDomain.com to myFirebaseProjectId.firebaseapp.com and it worked!